# Should I use a model archive in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `product` with a has_many relation `prices`. The `prices` table is growing rapidly, only few current prices are normally needed, but I want to keep all as a history.

So I am thinking to "archive" all old prices. How do I do that best?

Before I had a column `old` and was filtering them out when ever I only wanted the current prices. But now the `prices` table has 2.5 million rows and only 200k are needed in most situations. That's why I thought I would just create a new model `price_archive`. Copy all "old" `prices` to `price_archive` and delete it from `prices`. And all logic will be moved to a module, used by both models, so I can use `price` and `price_archive` in the same way.

Pros for the archive approach:

- ~ most of the queries are done on the smaller data set (200k, not much growing)

Cons:

- displaying both ordered by time needs to be sorted on some kind of joined data set, because times overlap. So it looks like `(part.prices.to_a + part.prices_archive.to_a).sort(&:time)`. Not a big problem, because this will be used very soldomly. But:
- I have other models (i.e. `order`) that use `prices` in a belongs_to relation, so those need `price_id` and `price_archive_id` (with one id always being nil), so that they still reference a `price`.

Most queries are: *show all prices for product (in a select box) and mark the price that is connected to this order (or add it to the select box, when it is archived)*

So the code would be something like:
`Order.where(*where*).includes(:part => :prices, :price, :price_archive)`

The db will query: `prices WHERE part_id = ?` [on 200k] + `prices WHERE id = ?` [on 200k] + `price_archives WHERE id = ?` [on 2300k, but with primary_key]
instead of `prices WHERE part_id = ?` [on 2500k, with normal index]

**Is there a better way or should I stay with the `old` column?**

Comment: Before you archive the prices, I would suggest doing a benchmark to see what the performance impact is of having 200k vs. 2.5M prices in the table. This will also give you a metric to determine the improvement achieved with your archive strategy (if you decide to archive, after measuring the performance improvement)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I don't know why I did not do that from the start. It "felt" like it would be getting significantly slower (but I did not benchmark it)